# pandas.DataFrame.astype raising "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\tG0001'"

Tags: python, pandas

While merging to `pandas.DataFrame()` objects, mismatch in the type of columns is causing an issue which im trying to address by converting the type of the mismatching columns using `astype()` method on the dataframes, which is actually throwing the title issue.

what, I'm trying to accomplish:

```py
sf_df = sf_df.merge(db_df, how='outer', indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

what im looking for:

`both below`

1. Ways in which the issue can be resolved
2. a workaround

- Sample df

```py
mng_ppl_id      loc               loc_name          update_d_t
   1116      \tG0001  GB-128 AUGER (992100) 2019-07-31 11:35:21
```

Comment: Please post small sample dataframes so that we have something to work with. `\tG0001` clearly isn't an integer, but what should it be? You may need to scrub this data (which begs the question where it came from) but we can't really suggest how without knowing what the data is.

Comment: ```mng_ppl_id      loc               loc_name          update_d_t
251        1116  \tG0001  GB-128 AUGER (992100) 2019-07-31 11:35:21``` I hope this helps.